# pass web service data to custom directive in angular js

Tags: angularjs, web-services, custom-directive

I have created one custom directive for multi-select in angular js and I'm passing data to multi-select directive as below:

```
<multiselect select-items="selectedCodes" data="names"
                    check-id="id1"></multiselect>
```

and scope in my js file is

```
scope: {
        data : '=',
        selectItems : '=',
        checkId : '@'
    },
```

Everything is working fine as expected, but only when I am hard coding data and using that in my directive.
However, when I am getting data from web service and using those variables in my directive, a null value is going instead of the web service data.

I think directive is loaded before my web service call returns data.

Can anyone suggest any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share some code

Comment: I have already shared the code for my custom directive usage and scope creation. Can u tell which code exactly you are asking for @ShashankVivek

Comment: The code for getting data from web service. We want to see that.

Comment: this.srchAllNames = function() {
        return new Promise(
          function(resolve, reject) {
           $http
             .get(
               'http://localhost:9060/EsipService/History/HistoryList')
             .then(function(response) {
              resolve(response.data);
              /*
               * console.log("data
               * "+response.data);
               */
             }, function(error) {
              reject([]);
             });
          });
       }

Comment: this.srchAllNames = function() {
        return new Promise(
          function(resolve, reject) {
           $http
             .get(
               'http://localhost:9060/EsipService/History/HistoryList')
             .then(function(response) {
              resolve(response.data);
              /*
               * console.log("data
               * "+response.data);
               */
             }, function(error) {
              reject([]);
             });
          });
       } @Pop-A-Stash